# First Name Last Name in Login not compulsory

Tags: magento-1, cart, login

I have made First Name & Last Name not compulsory in Magento. Now somehow on the cart page when I click on checkout button it goes to account info. Can I solve this somehow? Have never done such deep modifications in Magento and need an opinion on this.

Comment: Add more details to your questions like on which version of Magento you are on as well as what all you did so far.

Comment: Its Magento 1.9.1 i updated eav_attribute in database to 0